# Unwanted margin in box grid

Tags: html, css, margin

Quick CSS question that I can't figure out...and am a little surprised that I can't.

I'm trying to create a 2X2 grid of 4 boxes that touch each other with no margin in between; see the image:

[image: 2x2 grid]

However, when I implement the code below, I get a vertical line down the middle that I just can't get rid of.

**Here's my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#dash-container {
    width: 209px;
}
.dash-object {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}
#dash-edit{background:#FF7700;}
#dash-conference{background: #55bbff;}
#dash-upgrade{background: #333333;}
#dash-logo{background: #ffff00;}
</style>
</head>
<div id="dash-container">
<div id="dash-logo" class="dash-object"><span>Logo</span></div>
<div id="dash-conference" class="dash-object">Conference</div>
<div id="dash-edit" class="dash-object">Edit</div>
<div id="dash-upgrade" class="dash-object">Upgrade</div>
</div>
</html>
```

If you want to play with the html, you can [find it here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/boxes.html).

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Instead of doing `display: inline-block`, try `float:left`. I don't like using floats and I advice you to avoid them as much you can however, in some cases, they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline elements are sensitive to white space. Remove it:

```
<div id="dash-container">
    <div id="dash-logo" class="dash-object"><span>Logo</span></div><div id="dash-conference" class="dash-object">Conference</div>
    <div id="dash-edit" class="dash-object">Edit</div><div id="dash-upgrade" class="dash-object">Upgrade</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rcNEv/1/)**

Or by using HTML comment tags:

```
<div id="dash-container">
    <div id="dash-logo" class="dash-object"><span>Logo</span>
    </div><!--
    --><div id="dash-conference" class="dash-object">Conference</div>
    <div id="dash-edit" class="dash-object">Edit</div><!--
    --><div id="dash-upgrade" class="dash-object">Upgrade</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LhWDu/)**

Or by floating the inner divs:

```
#dash-container div {
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PFH7Q/)**